# Проект Эйлера №8 C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Решаю 8 задание из Проекта Эйлера на C#
Наибольшее произведение четырех последовательных цифр в нижеприведенном 1000-значном числе равно 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Найдите наибольшее произведение тринадцати последовательных цифр в данном числе.

Вот написал код

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            const String p = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";


            int largest = 0;
            int numm = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length - 12; i++) {
                numm = int.Parse(p.Substring(i, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 1, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 2, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 3, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 4, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 5, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 6, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 7, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 8, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 9, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 10, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 11, 1)) *
                           int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 12, 1));
                if (numm > largest) {
                    largest = numm;
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(largest);
            DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
            Console.WriteLine("Solution took {0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Получается ответ 2091059712, но он неправильный. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Comment: `int` не способен вместить `10 ** 13`. У вас переполнение.

Comment: Ещё одна вещь: подумайте как связано произведение пачки из 13 цифр и произведение следующей пачки, которая сдвинута на одну цифру. Вы можете вычислить следующее произведение из предыдущего одни делением и одни умножением. Будет быстрее.

Comment: Только не забудьте, что делить на 0 нельзя :)

Comment: @Harry, замечание про нули испортило мне настроение. И не понятно, как его поднять обратно (то есть как красиво решить задачу через произведение в окне, если есть нули.). Лучшее что я придумал: хранить произведение цифр в окне за исключением нулей и количество нулей в окне. Как-то не изящно.

Comment: если встретился 0, то можно сразу прыгать на 13 знаков вперед, потому что 13 произведений будут равны 0.

Comment: Забавно: судя по форуму на их сайте, примерно до марта-мая 2014 нужно было считать произведение 5 последовательных цифр, а не 13.

Comment: @Эникейщик, возможно, тогда был расчёт на 16-битные компиляторы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZTLbmNFEIb3fopWFjM2iUNVdVVf8AQWiF2EkFiwQCyC8QRLwZYvQYgozx6@PjMRjGCBJV9Od3XVf2uvT8v1afvy8vvdMZ3STbqoWUvVWiJrzlLMu3azUO2luluJ6tUtR@Sx452v0lsOk6xWq4eUbMVyj9qyNlF2na9WutfWQpvnFq1oFKmtqxpNvIdHD9Gaa4@Ws/awFtmkNQmGq4ULnRiu0cJyK1lCeCg9W5fOUI4YELM46GoprZfija7uYeMNMwZoi@KShWajr1ajW1bNxcx6g5Dl3ChomiOzSit1a9akOK9G1wGgwl1ytC7VegEDesDJXWqFPthyU4kBl8Lai3CyQtHcKnNbyx0MvXbhc0Dvpn3o1evg3aTnyuyoVjNWCM2Ag4ZqJjjg9JBeY2iDOoG@KAB5i@bMhx7zAkxwE2ccsruzhljuSmNTfKRFLr02BUttjkZIjSOhIAJcsUlk7WOTJ3O04BQ/NNcAoDCDXHQxlILqEKQVRFePHCpCZJppKbmCA4XwF6VFoIlrnkdq0MlhVqOhU4GlliFUVa@9g9etYwK2lOwlCCP@kEAdtrLhI1N1Moc0suyBdoSLKPMTyGRBDdUxk@gVxjsUhuZmRH4oZSij4zW0l2CmVqB1V@DhoEvDVwItZJjQMYQiJyQdV6ZMtYEWj0kMgnRsbiASogF/7BqQyVcNp04E9thBVsE2bgQ3TxATDQb/Aav7CDr16GjDChgE142zBAsTkTuq0sRKZ0prsJERWHo3nBdUoyK4GCZEhLuC3her2Wy9353Oabs7p9tvvuXya2bxYb@7T@vH43hezcbmn5vjfvw3CLvv98c0H38WhxtZpcM7Dq7S5eVhMUtp@z7NTz8efko3N@mtvB1Lib3p@IqHzcNpM62N7p/dpKl2OUpfx/529wdzPs5jYPpqqv1ijB5ItuwycamfIplAHN6drm83u/vzrx8BPf0NaUnFp7CWy/@G9fkE60P9K7T/x2wqmv@L2iJ9OdF68@YfvD40mLN@lbYLSI1zV@mwWM2eZ7OvsWX/sLn@4bg9b263u8384rvj/pfH9Tk9yXPa79KTPqc7nuz5@vopP19cpanV6fr7x59P5@N2dz/fDg6XejX0WjDl9XG7WL28/AU)

```
var s = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

const int LEN = 13;

long cur = 1;
int zeros = 0;

for (var q=0; q<LEN; ++q)
  if (s[q] == '0')
    ++zeros;
  else
    cur *= s[q] - '0';

long max = zeros == 0 ? cur : 0;
int i = LEN-1;

for (var q=LEN; q<s.Length; ++q)
{
  if (s[q-LEN] == '0')
    --zeros;
  else
    cur /= s[q-LEN] - '0';

  if (s[q] == '0')
    ++zeros;
  else if ((cur *= s[q] - '0') > max && zeros == 0)
    (max, i) = (cur, q);
}

Console.WriteLine("Product {0} on {1} at {2}..{3}", max, s.Substring(i-LEN+1, LEN), i-LEN+1, i);
```

```
Product 23514624000 on 5576689664895 at 197..209
```

Comment: Название временной переменной для индекса `q` вместо `i` довольно сильно сбивает с толку ))  И ладно бы `i` тоже была задействована под какой-то индексатор, но ведь нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, `i` - индекс конца вхождения. А индексаторы q, w, e я всегда делаю)))

Answer (score 5):

В общем получилось так и решение меньше 1 секунды

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
long largest = 0;
long numm = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < p.Length - 12; i++)
{
    numm = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    {
        //numm *= int.Parse(p.Substring(i + j, 1));
        numm *= (int)Char.GetNumericValue(p[i + j]);   
    }
    if (numm > largest)
    {
        largest = numm;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(largest);
DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
Console.WriteLine("Solution took {0} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Если проверять на 0 решение занимает больше времени